# Enable setup indexedDB for end to end ( Cypress tests)

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, indexeddb

I have a pwa project and use requests to db inside components, I use dexie as a wrapper
for this and when I want test my app I get next Error

[image]

Here is my code

```
function open() {
  const request = cy.window().then(win => win.indexedDB.open("timesheetsDB", 1))
  request.onerror = function(event) {

  };
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;

    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("jobs", { keyPath: "name" });

    objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
    objectStore.add({name: 'fsdf'});
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {
open()
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url :'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
  body : {
    email: "name",
    password: "Passwprd"
  }
}).then(function(response) {

}).then(()=>{
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
})
```

I already asked about this problem but solutions doesnt help solve this.
I want set up indexedDB for cypress enviroment to have ability open pages where I use requests to indexedDB

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your question?

Comment: I want set up indexedDB for cypress enviroment to have ability open pages where I use requests to indexedDB